# how do obj files work once loaded

Tags: 3d, java-3d, .obj

Can anyone provide me with a high level over view of how obj or other 3d formats work.
I'm trying to learn 3D programming for games but all the tutorials i've found so far only show how to create and manipulate primitives such as a sphere etc.
I'm using java but i also know C# and C++ i've just never done games programming or any 3D modelling.

Say for example if i have an obj file of a road and i load it. If any parts of the model is animated can i trigger that from inside the code or does it automatically happen?

The second thing, if i had another model which was a car, can i import that car and add it to the road in the first obj file? or would they need to be included in one obj file?

The last thing would be, if the car wheels were animated. Is there a way to stop them once i know the model is not moving in the scene, and then of course start them spinning again later?

I know it might be best to buy a book but i don't know if its something i want to get into yet, i'm just testing to see if i'll stick with it and asfter i decide i can then buy a 3d graphics book or similar. thanks

Comment: The WaveFront OBJ format doesn't support animation but it can be used to store a single mesh of a frame, for example in key frame animations. It can't be used for skeletal animations as far as I know. There are many engines and APIs with an OBJ importer including JOGL, JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation, LibGDX, Xith3D, Java3D, LibGDX, ...

Answer (score 0):

> Say for example....inside the code or
>   does it automatically happen?...The
>   second thing... The last thing would
>   be...spinning again later?

The answer for the three questions depends on what software you use for the 3D "world". If you use a framework, like [XNA](http://www.xna.com/), then you will have many helper functions for animations and the like. If you create the world with [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/), or the like, then you will be writing the code for the animations *(and just about everything else)*.

File formats for 3d assets vary wildly in what and how they store information. Some can contain entire scenes while others store only a single mesh. I would suggest you have a look at the [AutoDesk FBX](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=6837478&siteID=123112) site. Although the format is not technically documented, it seems reasonable place for a start as the format is generally stored in clear text and can contain variety of objects including [animations](http://area.autodesk.com/fbx2011). The [SDK, tools and viewers](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=6839916) are available for free...well free with registration:) Then grab [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), it is an excellent open source 3D editor that can handle most formats...could be helpful in learning what the different formats can do.

At the end of the day everything is just a triangle...with normals...a little color...maybe a texture...some shading...

Comment: thank you for responding. I have been playing around with blender so i'll have a look into your other links on AutoDesk FBX etc, thanks.